# How to install python dependency inside zalenium containers?

Tags: selenium, zalenium

I am using `docker-compose` file to set up the [zalenium](https://github.com/zalando/zalenium) environment. Due to an unusual file uploading behavior, I wanted to use [`robotjs`](http://robotjs.io/).

**Application Behaviour**: when click on the navigation button, the file uploading window opening automatically.

It is impossible to use `SendKeys` here because of that window pop up. I tried with `action` class. But it didn't work as expected. I can solve this by using `robotjs` library.

It is impossible to execute(`robotjs` actions) without `python 2.7` dependency inside zalenium containers.

Is there any way to install it?

Answer (score 0):

The Zalenium and docker-selenium images are based on Ubuntu 16. You could just extend the one you need and install Python there. Check first because probably it is already installed.